# customize google+ follow button

Tags: css, google-plus

I added a google + followbutton to my website with the following code:

```
    <g:plus href="https://plus.google.com/100827824854155199322" rel="publisher" width="250" height="69" theme="light">
```

I need the background of it to match the background of the container its in but im not sure how. I tried seeing what classes it was using and then setting them to my bg color with css but it did not work.

You can see what I mean on the right hand side on my website
http://www.beatmushroom.com/2012/05/phaeleh-afterglow-feat-soundmouse-akira.html#more

Comment: i'm pretty sure there's a transparency setting somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=162) to allow customization of badge background colors.

Answer (score 0):

After using Google Chrome -> Inspect Element and fidgeting around your website,

I think this would be your solution

```
.yeb{ 
   background-color:<insert your colour code>;
}
```

that would go into your css file.

Comment: The problem is that element is in an iframe and  can't be accessed from the container page.